# Getting Orthologs from biomart by using python

Tags: python, biomart

Can anyone share with me the script to extract orthologs of protein coding genes of a species i.e. let us say I wan to extract the orthologs of protein coding genes of human from mouse and cat genome. How I can do this by using python?